# VB.NET ULong overflow

Tags: vb.net

I have a timer which returns the time elapsed:

```
Public Function TimeElapsed() As ULong

    Dim ul As ULong
    ul = m_lEnd - m_lStart

    Dim ul2 As ULong
    ul2 = ul - m_lOverhead

    Dim ul3 As ULong
    ul3 = (ul2 / m_lFreq) * 1000

    Return ul3

End Function
```

Now I experienced the following variables:

```
m_lEnd =   935083366402
m_lStart = 935007142800
ul2 = 76223588
m_lOverhead = 14
```

This gives me an overflow in the line

```
ul3 = (ul2 / m_lFreq) * 1000
```

I can not see why and how to improve my bug.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: you do not mention what `m_lFreq` is

Comment: Yeah, what's in `m_lFreq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell the compiler you are doing the operation on a ULong... This is because the numeric literals default to `Integers`, so your trying to use an integer literal which will cause an overflow like your issue. You can force values to different types with the correct suffix. Literal values without a type suffix may only have values up to the range of Long. This case it's `ULong` so the suffix is: UL.

By the way this is a conversion error, turn Option Strict on...

```
 EX: Dim m_lEnd As ULong = 935083366402UL
```

Notice this at the end, this is what needs to happen.